# Unable to set DataGrid Virtualization Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to set the `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` of a `WPF` `DataGrid` to "Standard", but it doesn't appear to be valid for my `DataGrid`.  Is there something else I need to do?

The only option available for that is the `VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem` event, which doesn't help me very much.

Comment: That would work for a standard datagrid using recent versions of the .net framework. In what way is your datagrid not standard?

Comment: @Andy I think his problem is not that it doesn't work. His problem is that Intellisense doesn't show it, therefore he thinks it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, that's another explanation. Could be intellisense is broken. Stick the setting in there and spin it up... see what happens.

Comment: @Andy It does seem that it was Intellisense that was having the issue for some reason.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust Intellisense

Just paste `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` it will work

---

I played around a bit and it seems that Intellisense has problems when it comes to "inherited" `Attached Properties`

The corresponding field

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Some",...
```

And the Set and Get method

```
public static void SetSome(DependencyObject element, bool value){...}
public static bool GetSome(DependencyObject element){...}
```

must be present on the specific class to make Intellisense work

---

When you use `VirtualizingPanel`(base class of `VirtualizingStackPanel` / `VirtualizationMode` is also defined here) Intellisense is working as expected